# Deserialize a json string into case class when some of the attribute is missing in json string

Tags: scala, jackson, json-deserialization

I'm trying to deserialize a json string into case class when some of the attribute is missing in json string using jackson

eg.

```
case class ParsedPage(crawlDate: Option[String], domain: Option[String], url:Option[String], text: Option[String], abc: Option[Long])

val js1 = """ {
"crawlDate": "ddkke",
"domain": "0x20.be",
"url": "http://www.beer.com?title=99_Bottles_of_Beer&id=6214",
"text": "99 Bottles of Beer From Whitespace  Subpages",
"abc": 123
}"""

val js2 = """ {
"domain": "0x20.be",
"url": "http://www.beer.com?title=99_Bottles_of_Beer&id=6214",
"text": "99 Bottles of Beer From Whitespace  Subpages",
"abc": 123
}"""
```

should give me

```
Ans1 = ParsedPage(Some("ddkke"), Some("0x20.be"), Some("http://www.beer.com?title=99_Bottles_of_Beer&id=6214", Some("99 Bottles of Beer From Whitespace  Subpages"), Some(123)) 

Ans2 = ParsedPage(None, Some("0x20.be"), Some("http://www.beer.com?title=99_Bottles_of_Beer&id=6214", Some("99 Bottles of Beer From Whitespace  Subpages"), Some(123))
```

What I've tried

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind._
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.experimental.ScalaObjectMapper

val objectMapper = new ObjectMapper() with ScalaObjectMapper
objectMapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)

val ans = objectMapper.readValue[ParsedPage](js)
```

Getting exception:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Instantiation of [simple type, class ParsedPage] value failed: null
```

Comment: What about using a **Scala** library like **circe**, **upickle**, **play-json**, **jsonitter-scala**, etc? Rather than using a **Java** library?

Comment: I usually would like to avoid external libraries, our artifactory mostly doesn't have these libraries, but look like I have spray-json in there, so I could probably use that